# How to create an ODBC connection to specific database name

Tags: sql-server, windows, odbc

I'm trying to create an ODBC connection on a Windows 10 PC, for use with Excel, to an Azure SQL database.  The problem is we don't have permissions to connect to the `master` db (we don't own the Azure space or server), only our specific database.  When following the ODBC create connection wizard, there is no chance to specify the target database, therefore the connection attempt fails with Unauthorized.  When using SSMS, the connection dialog has an Options tab that allows you to specify the database you are connecting to.

How can I specify the database, or catalog, in the connection info for a new ODBC connection or DSN? I've tried including it in the db server field, like `myserver;mydatabase` or `myserver/mydatabase` with no luck.

Comment: Any reason not to use an newer ODC connection? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-excel?view=azuresql#create-a-permanent-connection-using-odc-file

Comment: Good idea, thanks.   This works to manually set up a connection.  I forgot to mention another requirement is to create an ```.odc``` file that can be shared with many users, including the password.  When I follow the instructions on your link for creating an ```.odc``` file it does not allow for specifying the db name.